# file-upload-with-preview.min.js showing error when uploading a large file

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-file-upload

file-upload-with-preview.min.js showing error when uploading  a large file (say a file of 30 mb).it is showing error.
the ajax call is performing on error function...

in my case I am trying to upload video of size up-to 100 mb.small files upto 10 mb are uploading fine

anybody have any idea on this ?

following is the details of
[file-upload-with-preview.min.js](https://github.com/johndatserakis/file-upload-with-preview)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of this library. Sorry you're having an issue using it.

Strange - I've never come across this type of size issue before. Perhaps the error is within the ajax call, and `file-upload-with-preview` is merely catching *that* error and showing it back to you.

I will note that I just recently made a very large `v5.0.0` update to the library - perhaps your issue no longer exists in the latest version.

Comment: the issue was solved later on... I appreciate your effort. thanks

Comment: there was no issue in plugin. the issue was with the function it was calling to ( had to set RequestSizeLimit ).